# Request thread interrupt not working on Ios

Tags: codenameone

I create a new thread, and y need to interrupt, I use the `thread.interrup()`, but when I throw request thread interrupt is not working on ios, works fine on simulator or in Android device.

I Attach code to try it.

My temporal solution is use a Flag to break while, but I want to use the InterruptedException

```
package com.kandy.forms;

import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.ui.Button;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;


public class Interrup extends Form {

    private Form previous;
    private Thread thread = null;


    public Interrup() {

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        Button newThread = new Button ("Start Thread");
        newThread.addActionListener((e) -> {
            thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            Log.p("thread working");
                        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                            Dialog.show("Message", "Interruption received", "Ok", null);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            //thread start
            thread.start();
        });

        Button interruptTreath = new Button ("Interrupt");
        interruptTreath.addActionListener((e) -> {
            Log.p("Interrupt Sended");
            thread.interrupt();
        });

        add(newThread);
        add(interruptTreath);       

    }

    public void show() {
        previous = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        super.show();
    }

    public void goBack(){
        previous.showBack();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported on iOS. Neither is stop etc. as those are pretty hard to get working consistently across platforms. This is especially true for iOS and the thread implementation in the JavaScript port.